# Find Canceled Publisher Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying with combine to manage my socket & handle messages

```
private var garbageBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func setupSocket() {
  
    
    SocketHelper.shared.startListene()
  
    garbageBag.forEach{$0.cancel()}
    
    SocketHelper.shared.publisher.sink {[unowned self] (sub) in
        print(sub)
        print("FINISH ")

    } receiveValue: {[unowned self] (value) in
        print("SUBSCRBE GOT VALUE ")
      
     }.store(in: &garbageBag)

}
```

This method call several times, so sink is also called many times to prevent that I have written like and it solves problem

```
    garbageBag.forEach{$0.cancel()}
```

But Now suppose 4 time this method will be called so in `garbageBag` there will be 4 Items

How can I remove canceled items

I know directly empty the Set is one solution but is there any way to check ?

Comment: Is it actually a valid scenario to have several subscriptions to the same publisher alive at the same time? If not, why don't you just store the `AnyCancellable` in a single variable and override it when `setupSocket` is called again?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes that is good point !  , My question is `AnyCancellable` is  `cancel()`  So How can I know that it is canceled or not ? is there any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check if an `AnyCancellable` is active or not. `Cancellable` (whose type erased form `AnyCancellable` is) only requires a `cancel()` method, there's no state handling requirement by the protocol.

However, `Cancellable` calls `cancel` when it is deallocated, so the best way to handle subscriptions in Combine is to throw away all references to `AnyCancellable` instances whenever you want to cancel a subscriptions.

So for your specific use case, the best approach is to only hold a single `AnyCancellable` instance, since it probably doesn't make much sense anyways to have several subscriptions to the same publisher.

You can decide if on subsequent calls to `setupSocket` you want to create a new subscription or simply do nothing and keep the previous one alive (however, I'd suggest doing the latter, since you're working with sockets).

```
private var socketSubscription: AnyCancellable?

func setupSocket() {
    // We only want 1 subscription
    guard socketSubscription == nil else { return }
    
    SocketHelper.shared.startListene()
    
    socketSubscription = SocketHelper.shared.publisher.sink {[unowned self] (sub) in
        print(sub)
        print("FINISH ")
     } receiveValue: {[unowned self] (value) in
        print("SUBSCRBE GOT VALUE ")
     }
}
```